# Device is not showing on network despite being on and ethernet cable plugged in - how to find

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

As the title says, I have a custom circuit board (MicroChip technology based)of some sort which definitely works (I can ping it on a different computer), however I cannot find it on the network using standard tools like nmap or arp -a on Debian Linux (these tools only show the connection after pinging the device on the other computer). Furthermore, the ethernet port of my debian board has an orange light when connected to the device.

Is there a way to check physical link connections and otherwise find this device, without running program A?
I do have its MAC address written down if that would help, and when program A is run the device has IP address of 10.0.0.100 .

-ethtool output:

```
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

mii-tool -v (eth5 is the connected port)

```
eth4: negotiated 1000baseT-FD flow-control, link ok
  product info: vendor 00:07:32, model 0 rev 0
  basic mode:   autonegotiation enabled
  basic status: autonegotiation complete, link ok
  capabilities: 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD
  advertising:  1000baseT-HD 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD flow-control
  link partner: 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD flow-control
eth5: negotiated 100baseTx-FD flow-control, link ok
  product info: vendor 00:07:32, model 0 rev 0
  basic mode:   autonegotiation enabled
  basic status: autonegotiation complete, link ok
  capabilities: 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD
  advertising:  100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD flow-control
  link partner: 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD flow-control
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed the isc-dhcp-server package (`apt-get install isc-dhcp-server`) to be able to host a LAN network on the debian computer.
After general configuration, put the IP address and MAC address of the device in the dhcpd.conf file